# Creating posts with acf_form() that has a relationship type field

Tags: plugins, forms

I'm trying to design a form that creates a post, with the help of Advanced Custom Fields (ACF).

The post has a custom post type of 'movie' and has custom fields of type 'relationship' that link to other posts of type 'genre'.

I use this code for the form

```
<?php
acf_form_head();
?>


<?php
acf_form(array(
    'post_id' => 'new_post',
    'post_title' => true,
    'new_post' => array(
    'post_type' => 'movie',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    ),
    'submit_value' => 'Create a new movie'
));
?>
```

which makes a form like this

[image]

but 'the Movie Genre' field isn't working, 
Thanks in advance for your time
any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify "'the Movie Genre' field isn't working"?

Answer (score 0):

If the values do not load there is either an error in JavaScript or an error in PHP during hte AJAX request.

JavaScript errors are usually caused by plugin conflicts. To begin debugging this start disabling other plugins to see if you can clear it up.

PHP errors during AJAX can be found by enabling error logging `https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG`